# How to configure Sentry client to bundle logs before send to Sentry Server

Tags: sentry

Assuming a large number of log events per second. Generally, it would make sense to bundle several log events, lets say over some temporal window (e.g. 1 min) or by number, before sending them to the Sentry server. It will reduce number of connections to the server.

I am using the Java client but couldn't find any configuration regarding this issue (https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/config/).

How to configure Sentry appropriately?

Comment: There isn't a way to bundle events inside of the SDK currently, but they are (by default) sent asynchronously (in a different thread than the main application thread). Sentry is releasing something soon that will help you do this outside of the SDK, though.